# Try to send an email null pointer exception

Tags: java, email, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get an email adresss from a database to make it the "InternetAddress recipient" but it returns me a nullPointerException and no more informations about the problem.
Here is the code :

```
public class SendEmail implements ISendMail {

@Override
public void sendEmail(Action action) {
    if (action.getCopieAction() != null) {
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            UtilisateurDao user = new UtilisateurDao();
            // récupération du code user de l'utilisateur

            Integer codeUserEnCopie = action.getCopieAction();
            System.out.println(codeUserEnCopie);
            Utilisateur util = user.findUserByCode(codeUserEnCopie);
            String mailUserCopie = util.getEMAIL();

            InternetAddress recipient = new InternetAddress(mailUserCopie);
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipient);
            message.setSubject("Vous êtes en copie d'une action");
            message.setText("Bonjour, l'utilisateur "
                    + action.getUtilCreation()
                    + " vous à mis en copie d'une action:"
                    + "Nom de l'action : " + action.getObjetAction()
                    + "Détails de l'action : " + action.getTexteAction()
                    + "Date de l'action : " + action.getDateAction());

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            System.err.println("Pas de transport disponible pour ce  
                            protocole");
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            System.err.println("Adresse invalide");
            System.err.println(e);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.err.println("Erreur dans le message");
            System.err.println(e);

        }

    }

}

}
```

The function that get the user in database

```
public Utilisateur findUserByCode(Integer codeUser) {
System.out.println(codeUser);
    Utilisateur util = new Utilisateur();
    util = null;

    try{

        System.out.println("ddd");
        Query requete = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u WHERE 
                    u.codeUtilisateur="+codeUser);
        requete.setParameter("codeuser", codeUser);
        util = (Utilisateur) requete.getSingleResult();

    }catch(NoResultException e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }


    return util;
}

  and the fonction that calls the fonction sendEmail

   public void creerAction(Action action) {


    try {
        ISendMail sendMail = new SendEmail();
        sendMail.sendEmail(action);
        System.out.println(action.getCopieAction());
        em.persist(action);

        em.flush();

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Action  " + 
  action.getObjetAction() + " ajouté avec succès avec en copie"+ action.getCopieAction());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can i do to have more information aboout the error?

STACKTRACE:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.
   invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.
    call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.
    invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.
    invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at $Proxy699.creerAction(Unknown Source)
at beans.ActionBean.ajouter(ActionBean.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.
     invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 32 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at dao.UtilisateurDao.findUserByCode(UtilisateurDao.java:157)
at dao.SendEmail.sendEmail(SendEmail.java:33)
at dao.ActionDao.creerAction(ActionDao.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.
    runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.
    invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.
    invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.
    doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.
     aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor615.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.
    intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.
    invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.
     intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.
    invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
... 43 more

   the DAO

public Utilisateur findUserByCode(Integer codeUser) {
System.out.println(codeUser);
    Utilisateur util = new Utilisateur();
    util = null;

    try{

        System.out.println("ddd");
        Query requete = em.createQuery(SELECT_BY_CODE_USER);
        requete.setParameter("codeuser", codeUser);
        util = (Utilisateur) requete.getSingleResult();

    }catch(NoResultException e){

        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }


    return util;
}
```

Comment: Provide the full stacktrace

Comment: Stacktrace was hidden at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: No it is the end of the stack trace i have nothing more

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

at dao.UtilisateurDao.findUserByCode(UtilisateurDao.java:157)

Your Exception should be originating there.

Comment: i have found one mistake , the getteur en setteur for email was bad but now the error has changed   i edit my post.

Comment: Well, the error still shows at the same place, at least if you updated it. Since we don't have your DAO code, it will be difficult, but you should try debugging with Eclipse or some IDE, it's much easier this way.

Comment: OK, you could change this: Utilisateur util = new Utilisateur();
    util = null;
by Utilisateur util = null; However that's not the problem. Could you add some comment on the line 157 of the DAO?

Comment: In the meantime, I would bet that the error is in this line: Query requete = em.createQuery(SELECT_BY_CODE_USER); Are you 100% sure that em is not null?

Comment: i think u are right... i have added 
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
     emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GA2010-ejbPU-dev");  ,
      
     
      em = emf.createEntityManager();

Comment: thank u! I am still having an error but i think i would be able to solve it